# $2k-1$ is an odd integer if $k$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on this advanced power rule problem:

[This is the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzAbi.png)

I understand everything up until step 4 in the problem hint. I am getting stuck with the statement that says:

"Since k is an integer it follows that 2k-1 is an odd integer. thus the equation simplifies to -1", since an x to an odd integer equals -1.

What i need help understanding is how can you make the jump in understanding to know that 2k-1 will ultimately be an odd integer. the way i see it is that if k turns out to be 1 then the polynomial will equal 1 since 2(1)-1=1. the only way i see it turning out negative is if k = 0...

how am i looking at this incorrectly?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking: if $k$ is integer $2k-1$ is odd simply means that for $k=1, 2, 3, ...$ $2k-1=1, 3, 5, ...$

Comment: Youre right. thanks!